# laravel recursion adding amount in parent

Tags: php, laravel

Good day everyone, I recently posted a question here regarding adding the amount to the next parent in loop and it goes well with the help of someone from laracasts,
he really helped me a lot and the code below is the result of that.

The scenario below the amount is not inserting because the records in database is not complete or some `parents` doesn't exist, and the current code is expecting some `parents` to skip.

**Problem Scenario #1**

```
+--+---------+--------+----+
|id|parent_id|rank    |name|
+--+---------+--------+----+
|1 |NULL     |Senior  |john|
|2 |1        |Basic   |jade|
+--+---------+--------+----+
```

1. Jade sent a link to a person and that person order without logging in (Guest)
2. After making an order the earnings will insert to the parents with rank in chain of `Basic -> Junior -> Premium -> Advanced -> Senior`
3. But in that case the it's `Basic -> Senior`, it skips `Junior, Premium, Advanced` so the amount for them should be inserted to `Senior` (John)

**Problem Scenario #2**

```
+--+---------+--------+----+
|id|parent_id|rank    |name|
+--+---------+--------+----+
|1 |NULL     |Senior  |john|
|2 |1        |Advanced|jane|
|3 |2        |Advanced|josh|
|4 |3        |Basic   |joey|
|5 |4        |Basic   |jade|
+--+---------+--------+----+
```

1. Jade sent a link to a person and that person order without logging in (Guest)
2. After making an order the earnings will insert to the parents with rank in chain of `Basic -> Junior -> Premium -> Advanced -> Senior`
3. But in that case the it's `Basic -> Basic -> Advanced`, it skips `Premium` so the amount for them should be inserted to `Advanced` (Josh), But
4. what's happening is, it also skips `Josh` because in the code it's expecting `Josh` rank is `Premium`.
5. The amount of `450` is inserted to `Jane` which is wrong because there is `Advanced` rank before `Jane`, therefore `Josh` should received the `450` instead of `Jane`
6. Jane should be ignored here because there's a first `Advanced` rank before here.

**Amounts inserted on the current code if that is the Scenario**

```
Jade = 50
Jane = 450
John = 250
```

**Amounts expecting to insert**

```
Jade = 50
Josh = 450
John = 250
```

### Code and Database I'm working on

**users table**

```
select `id`, `parent_id`, `rank`, `name` from `users`

+--+---------+--------+----+
|id|parent_id|rank    |name|
+--+---------+--------+----+
|1 |NULL     |Senior  |john|
|2 |1        |Advanced|jane|
|3 |2        |Premium |josh|
|4 |3        |Junior  |joey|
|5 |4        |Basic   |jade|
+--+---------+--------+----+
```

**Earning Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Earning extends Model
{

}
```

**User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected const RANKS = [
        'Guest',
        'Basic',
        'Junior',
        'Premium',
        'Advanced',
        'Senior',
    ];

    // startup call, earnings are added to parents,
    // unless order is from Guest
    public function recordEarning(array $amounts)
    {
        // as this method is called for the user who just
        // made a purchase, this user is required to have rank
        if (! $this->rank) {
            throw new \ErrorException('Cannot record earning for an inactive user');
        }

        $initialAmount = 0;

        if (! $this->exists && array_key_exists($this->rank, $amounts)) {
            // a guest record is not saved
            foreach ($amounts as $rank => $amount) {
                $initialAmount += $amount;

                if ($rank === $this->rank) {
                    // stop accumulating after reaching the guest's rank
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        $this->recordEarningToParent($this->rank, $amounts, $initialAmount);
    }

    protected function recordEarningToParent($currentRank, array $amounts, $carry)
    {
        $parentRank = $this->parentRank($currentRank);

        if (! $parentRank) {
            return;
        }

        $parent = $this->parent;

        if (! $parent) {
            return;
        }

        $amount = $amounts[$parentRank] + $carry;

        if (($parent->rank === $parentRank) && ($amount > 0)) {
            $earnings = new Earning();
            $earnings->user_id = $parent->getKey();
            $earnings->amount = $amount;
            $earnings->save();

            // as the amount was recorded, there
            // is nothing to carry to the next parent
            $amount = 0;
        }

        // recursive call to the next parent
        $parent->recordEarningToParent($parentRank, $amounts, $amount);
    }

    // find the parent rank, as nullable rank means inactive user
    protected function parentRank($currentRank)
    {
        $currentRankIndex = array_search($currentRank, self::RANKS);

        return self::RANKS[$currentRankIndex + 1] ?? null;
    }

    // relation definition, for reference
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public static function makeGuest($parentId)
    {
        $parent = User::query()->findOrFail($parentId);

        // find the first parent with a rank
        while (! $parent->rank) {
            $parent = $parent->parent;

            if (! $parent) {
                throw new \ErrorException('Could not find an active sponsor for this guest');
            }
        }

        $count = count(self::RANKS);

        $rank = 'Guest';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) {
            if (self::RANKS[$i + 1] === $parent->rank) {
                $rank = self::RANKS[$i];
                break;
            }
        }

        $guest = new User();
        $guest->rank = $rank;
        $guest->parent_id = $parent->id;
        $guest->parent()->associate($parent);

        return $guest;
    }
}
```

**Running the insertion of Earnings**

```
<?php

// ./routes/web.php

use App\Models\Earning;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    // new order from Guest
    $order = new Order();
    $order->sponsor_id = 5; // jade with rank = Basic

    if ($order->user_id > 0) {
        $user = User::query()->findOrFail($order->user_id);
    } elseif ($order->sponsor_id > 0) {
        $user = User::makeGuest($order->sponsor_id);
    }

    if ($user) {
        // Inform the amounts as an array
        $user->recordEarning([
            'Basic' => 50,
            'Junior' => 100,
            'Premium' => 150,
            'Advanced' => 200,
            'Senior' => 250,
        ]);
    }

    return Earning::query()
        // showing of earnings
        ->where('updated_at', '>', now()->subSecond())
        ->get();
});
```

Comment: Im gonna be honest with you, that's too much to read to understand your problem. You'd be much more likely to get good answers if you break this down to the bare bones needed to understand and replicate the issue. 4

Comment: @WesleySmith I've updated the question

Comment: Anyone please willing to help me? 